# Xcode 8 An error occurred during validation

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, app-store

[Screenshot of error prior to validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXB0Q.png)

[Screenshot of error after validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1KXL.png)

I used Cordova to build and IOS app which builds and runs without any issues. I'm trying to upload it to the app store using xcode and I keep getting an error when it tries to validate the archive.

I noticed that there are a couple of binaries with (0 Entitlements) which could be related to the issue but I have no idea how to remove them. I found some references to making sure your copy bundle resources don't have any unnecessary entries.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue. Been trying to resolve it for the past couple days without any success. Below are log files of error:

EDistribution.critical.log:

`2016-12-13 03:53:19 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error      Domain=DVTFoundationNSBundleAdditionsErrorDomain Code=1 "Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for fsevents.o" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for fsevents.o}`

Comment: which type of certificates you had created for app store .Thanks

Comment: @HassanALi I have two certificates. iOS Development and iOS Distribution.

Comment: Please Use IOS Distribution and Ad Hoc Certificate if you want to release your application on app store . Thanks

Comment: @HassanALi I set the code signing identity to my iPhone Distribution and set the Provisioning Profile to my Ad Hoc Certificate. Same result.

Comment: Please add the IOS  in Platforms

Comment: Seems like the 0 entitlements was coming from one of my node modules (webpack). I removed it before creating the archive and the issue went away.

Comment: Good  work please post it as your answer down here.